# Unable to paste into a protected worksheet using VBA, but can do it manually

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro that should copy a range of data from one workbook into another. The sheet in the other workbook is password protected, but if I copy and past manually, it allows me to do so. However, when I try and write this into my macro, it won't allow the paste.

Code is currently as follows:

```
Sub COPYT()
'
' COPYT Macro

    Range("B2:U109").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "_FileName_.xls"
    Windows("_FileName_.xls").Activate
    Range("H10").Paste

End Sub
```

When I run the macro as is, I get a

> Run-time error '438': "Object doesn't support this property or method"

and the debugger shows that the issue is with the last line `Range("H10").Paste`

I can't unprotect the sheet (compliance), and I can obviously get round this by just running the macro and then CTRL+V but (as this allows me to paste....), but I would rather that this was automated. Do I need a different syntax for the paste command due to the sheet being protected?

Thanks

Comment: When you copy/paste manually are you using the same range as the macro?

Comment: Yes everything the same. In fact, if I let the macro fail then I can just hit CTRL+V straight away and it finishes the job for me.

Comment: I don't understand how you can paste using Ctrl+V if the sheet is protected.

Comment: I don't understand that either....

Answer (score 0):

Paste is a method of the worksheet, not range. Try this. I have assumed sheet references but you may need to adjust.

```
Sub COPYT()

Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="_FileName_.xls")
wb.Sheets("compliance").unprotect    
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:U109").Copy wb.Sheets("compliance").Range("H10")
wb.Sheets("compliance").protect

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR. Thanks but that won't work as the sheet isn't just protected, it has a password on it, and like I said above I am not able to unprotect the sheet.

Comment: Ok sorry didn't read your question properly. Do you know how it is protected? Can you not unprotect it because you don't have the password?

Comment: That's right, don't have the password. I could throw in some code to break it open but because of corporate compliance I don't really want to do that...

Comment: Unless UserInterfaceOnly has been set to True, I don't think you can paste to a protected sheet. A good argument for someone to tell you the password?

Comment: Are you allowed to access a sheet's Range property at all if it's protected? If you're really willing, you might be able to simulate a copy & paste action using `SendKeys`.